# Trunacated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'ewf=12432'

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

The same piece of code works with the other table but when I put for the table it shows the "Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'ewf=12432'".

I don't have a double value either.
CODE:

```
$time = '2332800';

 $datee = date('Y/m/d H:i:s', time());
$date = strtotime($datee);

 $sql = "UPDATE hired_jobsonline SET expiry_status = '1'
        WHERE job_status = 'open' AND $date > unix_time_date + $time AND expiry_status = '0'";

if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "Succesfully Checked 27 Days..<br/>";
    } else {
echo "Error: Check 27 Days Online :" . $sql . "<br>" . $con->error;
}
```

The same code with a similar table works properly. I can't figure what exactly the problem is.

Working CODE:

```
$sql = "UPDATE hired_jobslocal SET expiry_status = '1'
        WHERE job_status = 'open' AND $date > unix_time_date + 2332800 AND expiry_status = '0'";

if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "Succesfully Checked 27 Days..<br/>";
    } else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $con->error;
}
```

Both of the table does not contain any DOUBLE values.

Error: `1496129785 - Current date time 
2017/05/30 13:06:25 - Current date time 
Error: Check 27 Days Online :UPDATE hired_jobsonline SET expiry_status = '1' WHERE job_status = 'open' AND 1496129785 > unix_time_date + 2332800 AND expiry_status = '0'
Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'ewf=12432'Copy to expiry_online table succesful. 
Hired Jobs online Status updated to 2.`

When I try to use PHPMyAdmin console I get this error.

```
#1292 - Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'ewf=12432'
```

Comment: Of course you have made a debug output of $sql in both cases and compared them …?

Comment: Yes, I have checked both of their outputs. I saw some posts related but those couldn't help me either.

Comment: Show what that looks like. We don’t know what $date contains.

Comment: $date is the current date time in Unix timestamp.

Comment: Try to use console, phpmyadmin to check if the query with the two different tables work correctly.

Comment: I get this error when i try to execute the query in console #1292 - Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'ewf=12432'

Comment: This message means that you are trying to compare different values type, should look at your table and try to check the data type and compare with the data you are checking in your code.

Comment: The data type am comparing with is a varchar in the table. Should it cause a problem ? Cause it works on the other table (hired_jobslocal).

Comment: You are trying to compare with what type of value in your php?

Comment: Try to use error_log to get the values ​​you are comparing in queries.  unix_time_date + $time and unix_time_date + 2332800.

Comment: Since it's a PHP code the value is a Unix timestamp and I didn't specify or convert to any specific data type.

Comment: The query is itself showing an error in the PHPMyAdmin so, I don't think the error should be in PHP.

Comment: The likely problem is that the values ​​you are comparing are not the same. In your first php query you add a string to a Unix timestamp and in the second you add an integer to the Unix timestamp. To debug, you need to know the result of the two sums. I am trying to see if there is a way to accomplish this.

Comment: I found out the problem. It was a string in between the numbers which I had put for testing a long time ago. The string could not get compared with the Unix timestamp which gave the trouble! Thanks anyways :)